# How to define an Integer bean in Struts 1.x

Tags: struts, javabeans

How do you instantiate an Integer bean, assigning a value, in the Struts 1.x framework?

```
<bean:define id="index" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
```

or

```
<bean:define id="index" type="java.lang.Integer" value="${0}"/>
```

Results in a: *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String*

```
<bean:define id="index" type="java.lang.Integer" value="<%=0%>"/>
```

Results in: *The method setValue(String) in the type DefineTag is not applicable for the arguments (int)*

```
<% java.lang.Integer index = new java.lang.Integer(0); %>
```

Works, but makes my eyes bleed.

Note that I had to refactor iterating over a list but am now applying a filter within the iteration.  This was the cleanest solution of all!

```
<logic:equal name="aplicacion" property="generico" value="false" indexId="index">
```

Maybe I need to go about this completely differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant by default bean type is of type

`java.lang.String (if you specify a value attribute)`

or

`java.lang.Object otherwise.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<bean:define id="index" type="java.lang.Integer" value="<%=java.lang.String.valueOf(0)%>"/>
```

Comment: Your code just caused the company cat to jump out of the window!... And a java.lang.ClassCastException.  It's almost the same the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<bean:define id="index" value = "0" />
```

Also visit http://j2ee.masslight.com/Chapter5.html for a working example.

Comment: Your example will work in many occasions such as comparing strings of numeric chars but...  This is still not an java.lang.Integer bean.  I wonder what will happen in the example in Chapter5 above, if someone initiated the bean with the value="07"?  TY anyway.