# how to mimic JSTL core set (c:set) in Struts 1.0.2

Tags: jsp, jstl, struts-1

Yes, that's right. Legacy app maintenance.

How do I mimic the `<c:set var='myvar' scope='requqst' value='val' />` in old school Struts 1.0.2?

Assume that I can't add JSTL to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it without touching Struts at all, using scriptlets – consider this a **last resort**:

```
<%
    request.setAttribute("myvar", "val");
%>
```

I'm not sure about Struts 1.0.2 ([it *should* be okay](http://struts.apache.org/1.0.2/api/org/apache/struts/taglib/bean/DefineTag.html)), but I know that in v1.3.8, this will also work:

```
<bean:define id="myvar" type="java.lang.String" value="val"/>
```

Be aware that [the allowed `type`s are extremely limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911476/how-to-define-an-integer-bean-in-struts-1-x).

Comment: Thanks Matt! I'll let this percolate a little, but I think this is the answer! I strongly dislike Struts 1 (or of any flavor really... being a Stripes committer).

Comment: BTW... i really, really dislike Struts after this experience. :)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I'm stuck on Struts 1.3.8 at work, and it's just _awful_